# $\sum{\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+3}}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2n}}}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Can we find a constant $a$ such that $\sum{\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+3}}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2n}}}$ converges?

Try: I am trying to compare the n th term with $\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}$ where c is a constant but failed.

Comment: Try combining all of the fractions into one fraction via a common denominator. Then do another comparison, but this time, what you'll be comparing to will be slightly different. (I'm going to guess something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4}}$).

Comment: I have tried but failed also.

Comment: Have you learned the limit comparison test? Also, forget what I said about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4}}$ - I lied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $n\to\infty$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\,n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\,n+3}}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\,n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\,n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}.
$$
This leads us to the choice $a=\sqrt2$. Then, for $k=1$ and $k=3$:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\,n+k}}-\frac12\,\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{2\,n}}=\frac{2\sqrt n-\sqrt{4\,n+k}}{2\sqrt{4\,n+1}\sqrt{n}}=-\frac{k}{2\sqrt{4\,n+1}\sqrt{n}(2\sqrt n+\sqrt{4\,n+k})}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+3/4}}= \sum \frac{2}{\sqrt{4n+3}} \leq \sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+1}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+3}} \leq \sum \frac{2}{\sqrt{4n}}=\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
Try cases $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $a\neq \sqrt{2}$, and check if they ever converge...